# Getting fileId from Intent sent by Google Drive

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

When Google Drive sends me its Intent after the user has selected a file that I am going to handle, the Uri that I get from Intent.getData() looks like this:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3Dw-X0owmgf2wbJ9Rb9kk8A7TBt6V0vQeMyIWXAs2ZOgD_RghO%0A
```

I assume that the "fileId" that I need to be able to request the file from Drive is somewhere in that last segment of the path. Are there any defined methods or other procedures for extracting it?

Comment: Um, why not use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to just use the `Uri`?

Comment: I need to read the file metadata to get the original file name and check the file extension.

Comment: FYI, I was able to use ContentResolver: Read to a temp file; attempt to open the file as a SQLite database; query to determine if it's one of my supported databases; if all OK, rename to where it's supposed to go. Thanks for the tip!